# IntelliJ does not resolve relative path for jade extend

Tags: intellij-idea, pug, webstorm

I have some simple setup:

app/layout/layout.jade
app/user/user.jade

`user.jade` should extend `layout.jade`

I set the basepath for jade to `%projextdir%/` (which contains the app folder from above)

Intelij can resolve the paths:

```
// relative:
extends layout/layout
extends ../app/layout/layout
// absolute:
extends /app/layout/layout
```

Which leads to the paths in jade:

```
// relative:
%projectdir%\app\user\layout\layout.jade // wrong
%projectdir%\app\app\layout\layout.jade // wrong
// absolute:
%projectdir%\app\layout\layout.jade // ok
```

So only absolute paths are resolved correctly.

The Correct relative paths for jade would be:
    extends ../layout/layout

But IntelliJ can not resolve it. So I have no IDE support (e.g. strg+click).

Is there a known bug? Or any solution to fix this behaviour in IntelliJ?

Comment: can't recreate... the onlt path that is resolved for me is 'extends ../layout/layout'. Something must be wrong with your project setup. I'd suggest contacting support, providing a project that shows up the issue. BTW, how did you set the basepath for jade?

Comment: I set the base path using `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, ''));` - the intelliJ problem als oappears for typescript references that are deeper than 1 folder.

Comment: WebStorm doesn't use your base path settings at all when resolving paths - they are resolved relative to the current file or project root ('absolute' paths - starting with slash). Your issue is likely caused by Angular plugin bug - [WEB-11359](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11359)

Comment: I was able to fix it by renaming my app folder. It's somehow related to the folder name. Strange bug ...

Comment: yes, the bug is indeed related to 'app' folder name. it's fixed in WebStorm 9/Idea 14